# Recording Non-Http/Https Pop-up requests in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am recording one web application. At one point a pop-up appears (Application Expected Behavior) which is non-https/non-http window, which is not getting recorded in JMeter. How can I record this non-http/non-https pop-up window in JMeter. I have attached the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter records every action which triggers a [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), if opening a pop-up doesn't generate any traffic, i.e. happens solely on the client-side as a result of some [JavaScript Popup](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp):

1. You won't be able to record it with JMeter
2. You don't need to record it with JMeter as you're load testing the [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend_and_backend#Back-end_focused) and need to focus on simulating real browser network footprint.

Double check whether the popup triggers a network request or not using "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and if it doesn't - just ignore it. If it does - check [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally any abnormal behaviour is reflected there.

If you need to check frontend performance - you won't be able to do this using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers,  you will have to go for [WebDriver Sampler plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mixing-selenium-into-your-load-scenario) or something like [Lighthouse](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/).